# iOS - Swift - Some audio when recording reached the maximum allowable length

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I implemented a video recorder in Swift as part of an iOS app, where I set the maxRecordedDuration for the video output to 4 seconds (30 frames per second):

```
self.videoOutput?.maxRecordedDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds( 4, 30 )
```

When the user starts recording there are two scenarios that can occur:

1. The user decides to stop recording before the max recording duration is reached.
2. The max recording duration is reached before the user stops the video recording.

In any of the two cases both

```
func captureOutput( captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]! )
```

and

```
func captureOutput( captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError! )
```

will be triggered as they are part of the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`, which is responsible for responding to events that occur in the process of recording a video file (corresponding to the Apple documentation).

The video output works completely flawless in user scenario 1. However, in user scenario 2 the video output is missing some audio bits. In other words, at the end of the video, the video is still playing while there is no sound.

I am aware that when the max recording duration is reached, `func captureOutput( captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError! )` throws the following error:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11810 "Recording Stopped" UserInfo={AVErrorTimeKey=CMTime: {120/30 = 4.000}, AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=true, NSLocalizedDescription=Recording Stopped, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The recording reached the maximum allowable length., NSUnderlyingError=0x175324c0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16413 "(null)"}}

I added some code to the beginning of the method to check whether the recording was still successfully finished when that error will be thrown:

```
    // Error during video recording
    if let error = error, let finishedSuccessful = error.userInfo[ AVFoundation.AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey ] as? Bool
    {
        // Video was not successfully recorded
        if !finishedSuccessful
        {
            return
        }
    }
```

**Even though the code runs as expected, the video outcome has some missing audio in the end as mentioned above. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this bug?**

Comment: I'm having exact same problem..
when I record for 10 seconds it works perfect but longer recording , audio track is missing from file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about fixing the bug, but there is a way to avoid it. Ignore the `maxRecordedDuration` feature and build your own countdown timer. That way you would make sure scenario 1 is the only possible scenario.

There are multiple ways to achieve that. A very simple one could be to perform `stopRecording()` with a delay of X seconds from the moment recording started.

Comment: The problem with this is that the delay is not exact and strangely neither is maxrecordedduration. Do you know of any other EXACT method to get it to stop exactly like 8.0 instead of 8.5366666? Even timers are not exact...

Comment: @simplexity probably a bad idea, but maybe you can run the timer till 1 sec before it should end and then have a 0.01s delay script running and checking if it should execute stopRecording(). If anything, that should bring you closer to the time you really want

Comment: @simplexity awesome. If you find a better solution, please post it here